# Why can't my RCP Application detect migration files in deployed Flyway / Spring project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, eclipse-rcp, flyway

I have a Spring/H2/Hibernate project and am trying to integrate flyway. The project is built using maven and creates a Jar that I am then including in other applications that access the database.

My issue is that when I test the spring project flyway works fine and creates my schema, however when I deploy the lib in another project it doesn't seem to find the migrate scripts. I have checked, they are in the jar file.

My spring config:

```
<bean id="flyway_database_1" class="org.flywaydb.core.Flyway" init-method="migrate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource1" />
    <property name="locations" value="com.domain" />
    <property name="sqlMigrationPrefix" value="DATABASE_1_V" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource1" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.1.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.1.url}" />
</bean>
```

My application finds the Spring Context XML file and the properties file both in the classpath but flyway doesn't seem to find the sql files.

for my locations I have tried "com.domain", "com/domain", "classpath:/", "classpath:/database1/migration/"

All of these work in the Spring project and then fail to detect the files when it's jar is included.

Any ideas on why this would be?

**EDIT:** I think this may be due to me including the jar in an RCP application maybe there's some different way FlyWay detects files than Spring?

**EDIT** 
[A zip containing an example of this happening the RCP project includes the DB project and flyway cannot detect the migration files.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzXkqSHXmwxJc1FtR1JQblNQYWM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Are you deploying to a case-sensitive platform (say Linux) while developing in a case-insensitive one (say, Windows?)

Comment: Do you have any logs?

Comment: @Michael no these are both running in the same eclipse workspace.

Comment: @Ueli No I don't I can't see how to get flyway logs, the first error I get is when the app tried to access a non existent DB table. Flyway has generated it's audit table but hasn't put in any entries so it's got a connection to the embedded database, so I know the spring config is working. It just doesn't seem.to find the SQL files.

Comment: just guessing: com/domain instead of com.domain? The documentation always uses "/" as a directory separator.

Comment: I should have said. I've tried dots, slashes classpath, non classpath. All of them work in the spring project and then fail when the jar is included in the application.

Comment: How your RCP application loads the Spring Context? Could you increase the log level for the Flyway classes for further info?

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: Please could you give the full path of the folder where your migration scripts are located in within the JAR file?

Comment: Anywhere. It doesn't work when I put them in the root, or when I put them in a package folder, or anything.

Answer (score 6):

What is the version of `flyway-core` you are using? There was a bug in the flyway for scanning sql scripts from jar file. Please see https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/1261 for details. This issue has been fixed in 4.1 release so you can try by adding the latest version of `flyway-core`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**EDIT**

Can you try to give full path of location using `filesystem:` like below and see if it is working?

```
<property name="locations" value="filesystem:C:/project/spring-flyway/src/main/resources/db/migration" />
```

**EDIT**

This is a bug and need a fix at Flyway. https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/1630. For time being you can create db/migration folder in your plugin project and keep migration sql files there.

Comment: @Link19 Please see my EDIT in answer and try full path of location using filesystem: prefix.

Comment: Yes that does work, it's how I've gotten around the problem for now, however I don't want to use it like that.

Comment: does that give you a hint or were you suggesting that is a solution? I have included a project that reproduces the error in my original question now.

Comment: Ah well that's a shame, I staked a lot of rep on that, hoping I was doing something wrong.

Comment: Why did you undo the select  answer you had accepted earlier? This is the correct answer. I know you have put a lot of repo on bounty but you are going to lose that anyway as that is irreversible.